# How are the essential upper and lower limits defined?

Tags: reference-request, notation

What means 
\begin{equation}
\operatorname*{ess\,lim\,inf}_{x\to x^*} F(x)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\operatorname*{ess\,lim\,sup}_{x\to x^*} F(x)?
\end{equation}
Sorry I also do not know in what conditions this notation make sense for some $F$.

Comment: Probably related to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_supremum_and_essential_infimum

Comment: Is related but it is different.

Comment: Of course, which is why I said related. I bet yours is defined in terms of that link.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that upper limit can be expressed in terms of suprema over shrinking punctured neighborhoods of $x^*$: 
$$
\limsup_{x\to x^*} F(x) = \lim_{r\to 0} \sup_{0<|x-x^*|<r} F(x)
$$
Replacing supremum with essential supremum, we get the concept of essential upper limit:
$$
\operatorname*{ess\,lim\,sup}_{x\to x^*} F(x) = \lim_{r\to 0} \operatorname*{ess\,sup}_{0<|x-x^*|<r} F(x)
$$
Similarly,
$$
\operatorname*{ess\,lim\,inf}_{x\to x^*} F(x) = \lim_{r\to 0} \operatorname*{ess\,inf}_{0<|x-x^*|<r} F(x)
$$

The notation makes sense for every real-valued function; the value of the limits may be $\pm \infty$, but they are always defined. Above I assumed that the domain of definition is a Euclidean space. The same definition works for metric spaces. And even for general topological spaces, since the limit $r\to 0$ is really just the infimum or supremum over all neighborhoods $N$ of $x^*$.

$$
\operatorname*{ess\,lim\,sup}_{x\to x^*} F(x) = \inf_{N} \operatorname*{ess\,sup}_{x\in N\setminus \{x^*\}} F(x)
$$
$$
\operatorname*{ess\,lim\,inf}_{x\to x^*} F(x) = \sup_{N} \operatorname*{ess\,inf}_{x\in N\setminus \{x^*\}} F(x)
$$

Comment: I thank your answer. But, what does $\operatorname*{ess\,sup}_{0<|x-x^*|<r} F(x)$ mean? Would you mind give a reference?

Comment: Essential supremum is defined in the first link under your question.

Comment: But there $\operatorname*{ess\,sup} F(x) = inf\{ a : \mu(\{x:f(x)>a\}) =\emptyset $. Can I conclude $\operatorname*{ess\,sup} F(x) = inf\{a: \mu(0<|x-x^*|<0 : \{f>a\}) =\emptyset $?